# SQL - Query for a meeting room

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a help to create a query to return if the period selected already has a meeting in the room.

I have table `rep_reuniao` with the following design

```
  ID           --> int
  ROOM         --> int
  DATE_BEGIN   --> DATETIME
  DATE_END     --> DATETIME
```

Now an insert of a row in the table `rep_reuniao` looks like this

```
 ID            --> 1
 ROOM          --> 2
 DATE_BEGIN    --> 2014-02-21 17:00:00
 DATE_END      --> 2014-02-21 18:00:00
```

I will create an Jquery Ajax script to return a `true` or `false` JSON response based on the selected datetime.

So the query will have the `ROOM`, `DATE_BEGIN` in this format `2014-02-21 17:00` and `DATE_END` in the same format `2014-02-21 18:00`

I Have checked another responses, but the most of them is a query to show the Rooms available. In my desing, a room is always available, except when exist a register in the table.

```
Example 1
```

ROOM `1` is already in use from `2014-02-21 17:00:00` to `2014-02-21 18:00:00`

Need create a query to return a value (Anything) if the user select a room in:

```
BEGIN = 2012-02-21 16:30:00 
END = 2012-02-21 17:30:00
```

See? The room in use in the table begins 17:00 so today my query easly return a value if the begin selected by the user is the same. But the End date selected by the user is between the time already in use.

Well, the selected time by the user cannot be in use lookin into the begin date and end date. I have no ideas right now, anyone can help me?

You need to check if one date range overlaps another date range.

```
New Date Range =               |-----------|
Test1          =      |=====|
Test2          =            |=====|
Test3          =                  |=====|
Test4          =                        |=====|
Test5          =                              |=====|
Test6          =            |=================|
```

Only Test1 and Test5 do not overlap.

Sorry if has any English errors. If someone are able to fix, I'll appreciate.

Comment: why your question has tags for both mysql and sql-server?

Comment: Anyone from any database are able to help me. I need the logic not the correct sql language. Thanks!

Comment: Well queries are used to return DATA, not messages. You are looking for a query something like this (I'm not great at SQL so it will just be logic surrounding SQL).. `If SELECT Count(ROOM) FROM rep_reuniao WHERE User's_proposed_date/time BETWEEN DATE_BEGIN And DATE_END > 0 Then _YourMessageHere_`

Comment: Hi Mark, i dont need a specific message, just return anything because my test is based on `if query.EOF then`. I will test your example.

Comment: Dosn't worked. I choose from '2014-02-21 16:30' to '2014-02-21 18:01' and don't return anything. See? The beggining if before the result that already exist, and the end date don't exist in the table, so the SQL return nothing (Room available). :(

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying.. Can you re-word your last comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, if the query returns any rows that means the room is already booked. 
A simple explanation is the user gives `@UserBegin` and `@UserEnd` time that they need the room for.

And if the @UserBegin is between a row's begin and end then it is already booked.

Similarly, if the @UserEnd is between a row's begin and end, even then the room is booked.

```
SELECT * 
FROM rep_reuniao r
WHERE (@UserBegin BETWEEN r.DATE_BEGIN AND r.DATE_END)
    OR (@UserEnd BETWEEN r.DATE_BEGIN AND r.DATE_END)
    OR (@UserBegin <= r.DATE_BEGIN AND @UserEnd >= r.DATE_END)
```

From here you can extend this to return a bool like shown

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS ( /* The above query */ ) THEN 0 ELSE 1
```

This should return 1 or 0, when the room is available or not respectively.

Comment: OP asked for a value to be returned if the record within the date/time values exists, not just SQL.

Comment: If you know how to do it maybe you should throw it in there and help 'em out ;)

Comment: This doesn't handle when the entire date in the table falls between `@UserBegin` and `@UserEnd`.

Comment: @user2989408 It will **not** because `@UserBegin` will fall before `r.DATE_BEGIN` and `@UserEnd` will fall after `r.DATE_END`.  Both conditions will return **false**.

Comment: @JonSenchyna You are right, I misread your comment, and will add that condition to the answer too.

Comment: @user2989408 You don't need a third case.  You just need to find when the start date of one of the date ranges falls within the other range, as I did in my answer.  Overall, GordonLinoff's answer outperforms both of ours.

Comment: @JonSenchyna Yes, Gordon's answer is the best answer.

Comment: @user2989408 your way is working better than GordonLinoff's answer.

Answer (score 5):

The correct logic over overlapping timeframes is that two time frames overlap when both these conditions are true:

- the first starts before the other ends
- the first ends after the other starts

In SQL, these can be expressed easily:

```
SELECT r.* 
FROM rep_reuniao r
WHERE @UserBegin <= r.DATE_END AND
      @UserEnd >= r.DATE_BEGIN;
```

Note that this can return multiple rows, when multiple meetings occur during the specified timeframe.

If you want true/false or 0/1, then use aggregation and `case`:

```
SELECT (case when count(*) = 0 then 'false' else 'true' end) as HasOverlappingRooms
FROM rep_reuniao r
WHERE @UserBegin <= r.DATE_END AND
      @UserEnd >= r.DATE_BEGIN;
```

Comment: This does not handle when the range between `@UserBegin` and `@UserEnd` falls within a range in the table.

Comment: @JonSenchyna . . . Of course it does.  Think about it harder.  Note that the *begin* date is compared to the *end* date and vice versa.

Comment: Is `>= <=` the preferred method over `BETWEEN`? (I'm not sure, just asking)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I stand corrected.  I misread your answer (and had just finishing making that correction to another answer).

Comment: @MarkLaREZZA . . . The logic in this answer is not amenable to `between`.  That would produce different results.

Comment: @MarkLaREZZA `BETWEEN` is a `>= <=` check.  The **correct** answers posted require the use of two `BETWEEN`s (4 total date comparisons), whereas this answer just requires one `>=` and one `<=`.

Comment: Got it! Thanks @GordonLinoff and Jon Senchyna. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @GordonLinoff +1 This is the smart way of doing it.

Comment: This dosn't worked when the @UserBegin is before a date already in use and @UserEnd is between a record in the table. Example:

`Record in the table (BEGIN, END, ROOM)`
2014-02-21 17:40:00.000, 2014-02-21 18:40:00.000, 1

`SELECT r.* 
FROM rep_reuniao r
WHERE '2014-02-21 17:00' <= r.DATE_BEGIN AND
      '2014-02-21 18:01' >= r.DATE_END and ROOM=1`

This returns nothing. And should return something.

Comment: @MarceloMadnezz You have `@UserBegin` and `@UserEnd` mixed up in your example query.  You should be checking for where `@UserBegin` is before the record's `DATE_END` and where `@UserEnd` is after the record's `DATE_BEGIN`.

Comment: Try this: `SELECT r.* 
FROM rep_reuniao r
WHERE '2014-02-21 18:01' <= r.DATE_BEGIN AND
      '2014-02-21 17:00' >= r.DATE_END and ROOM=1`

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following query.  It should catch when a date in the table falls within your range, or when you range falls within a date in the table:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AlreadyBooked
FROM rep_reuniao r
WHERE (@UserBegin BETWEEN r.DATE_BEGIN AND r.DATE_END)
    OR (r.DATE_BEGIN BETWEEN @UserBegin AND @UserEnd)
```

The query checks for any rows where either `@UserBegin` falls within the range in the row or where the row's start date falls withing `@userBegin` - `@UserEnd`.  It will find cases where the ranges partially overlap, or where either range falls within the other.

Comment: I would recommend using GordonLinoff's answer, as I believe it is more efficient.